# Suppose $X$ has a clopen subset $A.$ Show that $B = X\setminus A$ is also clopen.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Here is the question:

> [image]

Having proved problem I, could anyone give me a hint on how to prove problem 2(a) and (b), please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just recall that
$$
\text{$S$ is open}\Longleftrightarrow\text{$X\setminus S$ is closed}
$$
and apply it (twice) to $S=A$ and $S=X\setminus A$.

For b) is just the same adding the extra ingredient that when $f$ is continuous $f^{-1}$ sends open sets to open sets and closed sets to closed sets.